# Difficulty integrating a look and feel to my project

Tags: java, module, look-and-feel, module-info

This is how I proceeded.

**1.** Ensure that your classpath contains all required Synthetica libraries, means
the core library (synthetica.jar) and the used theme library.
Note: In Synthetica V3 the core library contains Synthetica core files only,
no themes. Since V3 the standard theme is *not* any longer part of  the core
library! So you have to put all required theme libraries  on  your classpath
or modulepath too.
[Library image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJOrm.png)

**2.** Enable Synthetica  Look and  Feel on application startup.  Theme class names
follows the syntax below:
de.javasoft.synthetica.[theme].Synthetica[theme]LookAndFeel

```
 //Example - Dark theme:

 import de.javasoft.synthetica.dark.SyntheticaDarkLookAndFeel;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
   UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaDarkLookAndFeel();
   EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new MyDesktopApplication());
   ...
```

[Import image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTdqz.png) ,
[Implementation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HZ59.png)

JPMS module names

**3.**  All modules of Synthetica V3 are listed below.
Synthetica BlackMoon theme      ->  synthetica.theme.blackmoon (...)

[Module export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idi7Z.png)

**4.** Problem :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel (in module synthetica.base) cannot access class sun.swing.DefaultLookup (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.swing to module synthetica.base
at synthetica.base/de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaLookAndFeel.initialize(SyntheticaLookAndFeel.java:836)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:586)
at LogicielDeTrading/base.Main.main(Main.java:397)
```

**5.** The problem wouldn't certainly be solved including all the modules from the JDK. -> [Java: Is `sun.awt.image` package deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801778/java-is-sun-awt-image-package-deprecated/53802790#53802790)
So i add in JVM:

```
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.image=<yourModuleName>
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED
```

**6.** Same problem.

*Source : [LookAndFeel Java Synthetica in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820757/lookandfeel-java-synthetica-in-eclipse)
Source : [Java: Is `sun.awt.image` package deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801778/java-is-sun-awt-image-package-deprecated/53802790#53802790)
Source : [How to add a look and feel to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578661/how-to-add-a-look-and-feel-to-my-project)*

Comment: No answer? the post is still relevant.